# How to define a timestamp field using drupal6 schema

Tags: entities, database

In this way I can create a table with a timestamp field in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  name varchar(255)
);
```

Which would automatically insert a timestamp value each time a new row is inserted.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('bar');
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | created_at          | name |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 2012-03-12 10:47:02 | bar  |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

How can I create a timestamp field like this using the drupal6 schema API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you cannot do this because [the schema API does not support the TIMESTAMP type](http://drupal.org/node/215821).

> The MySQL implementation of the Schema API implements the datetime field using MySQL's **DATETIME** type. That type does not support automatic initializiation/update to the current time.
>
> MySQL's type **TIMESTAMP** supports automatic initializiation/update to the current time. Switching from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP is not an option, though:
>
> TIMESTAMP behaves differently in MySQL versions 4.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.6
>   The first TIMESTAMP column in a table behaves different than other TIMESTAMP columns in that table.